# Serial.println using Registers in ATMEGA328P

Tags: arduino, uart, serial, atmega328p

I have worked with ATMEGA328P using Arduino libraries, but new to actual register level coding. To start with that, I have written code for basic `Serial.print` in AVR STUDIO IDE. I tried to check it's output on Serial monitor of Arduino IDE. I could not see any result, as transmitter LED of Arduino UNo board is not blinking, I conclude that I have done something wrong, but unable to debug it. I would appreciate if one can suggest books to learn Register level coding for Atmega328P.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void beginSerial(int baud){
    uint16_t UBRR_value=lrint((F_CPU/(16 *baud))-1);
    UCSR0A = 1<<U2X0;
    UBRR0H=(unsigned char) (UBRR_value >>8);
    UBRR0L=(unsigned char) UBRR_value;
    UCSR0B=(1<<RXEN0) | (1 <<TXEN0);
    UCSR0C=(1<<USBS0) | (3 <<UCSZ00);
}


int main(void)
{
    beginSerial(9600);
    DDRB |=(1<<PINB5);
    PORTB &=(1<<PINB5);
    while (1) 
    {
        while(! (UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
        UDR0 ='A';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a semicolon at the end of your while loop in main. Currently it'll only write to the register when `UDRE0` is **not** set.

Comment: Baud rate calculation is also wrong as with U2X feature one bit is 8 clocks.

Comment: Please enter your code not as an image.

Comment: Corrected major mistake ';', still not able to see the correct character on the serial monitor, @Justme would u explain the mistake in U2X assignment

Comment: You can configure the UART for 8 or 16 times oversampling.  You configured it for 8x but are calculating for 16.  Either do not set U2X0, or change the clock division calculation to use 8.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I not good with datasheet surely work on it. Corrected above changes, observed Tx led is blinking..Tx is happening but not able to see the output on serial monitor.